can lit elements also be used without shadow dom - are there any risks?
we need web components and use lit elements in our web application. however, the dom shadows cause problems not only in the css area (access not possible, no global css sheet).
what is the biggest risk if we simply do without shadow doms?
createRenderRoot() { return this; } is such an easy way - what is the danger / bad effect i dont see?
Thanks and have a nice rest of the week

As for other options, I don't believe that React, or Vue currently have the ability to disable shadow DOM when creating custom HTML elements.
However, Stencil.js, Svelte, and Angular can all be used to create custom elements without implementing the Shadow DOM. I know that Stencil will also allow you to use slots without the Shadow DOM, but I can't speak for the others.
The only "risk" that I would advise being aware of is that your global CSS styles can and will bleed into your components.

i can t change the framework, but that confirms my opinions - thanks :)

Lit does have the ability to opt out of shadow DOM by overriding createRenderRoot as mentioned in the question. Opting out of shadow DOM removes the ability to use slots for composition, and removes the style and DOM encapsulation.

@AugustineKim, you are correct about createRenderRoot. Edited answer to reflect that fact.

Removing Shadow DOM does remove encapsulation however, in my opinion I believe that it's a better approach to default to light DOM and only use shadow DOM when it's genuinely needed (like a browser extension for example). The main issue for me is accessibility, which is a dealbreaker when it comes to form controls or anything that requires keyboard accessibility, which is most UI components.  https://leobalter.github.io/cross-root-aria-delegation/
